# Why are effect-less functions executed?

Tags: programming-languages, language-agnostic, compiler

All the languages I know of would execute something like:

```
i = 0
while i < 100000000
    i += 1
```

..and you can see it take a noticeable amount of time to execute.

Why though, do languages do this? The only effect this code will have is taking time.

edit: I mean inside a function which is called

```
function main(){
    useless()
}
function useless(){
    i = 0
    while i < 100000000
        i += 1
}
```

Comment: Perhaps taking time *is* the desired effect of such code?

Comment: How is that loop effect-less? If the loop does not execute, i will stay 0. If it does execute, i will be 100000000. So clearly you can't just remove the loop. You could replace it with `i = 100000000` though (and that's exactly what gcc does if optimizations are enabled).

Comment: A couple decades ago, I worked on code that did the above as a "sleep()" routine.  This works in single process environments where the clock as a fixed rate.  (Probably not something today's developers would ever encounter.)

Comment: I'm pretty sure most good compilers will optimize this out[Assuming you enabled optimizations]. Those who don't just didn't spend the time to add that feature to their optimizer.

Comment: The compilers are smart, of course. But they aren't designated to think instead of a programmer who would write something like that without any goal.

Comment: Counter-based busy waits are usually not the best way to impose time delays, but sometimes they are.  In 1993, I was working on a data acquisition system that used a 486/50 and a 16-channel A/D converter board.  The board was designed when the PC/AT was the state of the art, and its registers and control logic were physically not capable of responding as fast as the 486/50 was hitting it with setup data.  The fix was to add a little 100-instruction inline assembly wait loop after each register write.  That gave the board a few microseconds to grind its gears, which it desperately needed.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

In general, its hard (that is, undecidable) to prove if something is a silly busy loop (that could be optimized out) or an infinite loop (that cannot be optimized out withuot changing the meaning of the program). Does the [following code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collatz_conjecture) loop forever or does it stop?

```
var n = //some positive integer
while(n != 1){
   if(n % 2 == 0)
      n = n/2;
   else
      n = 3*n+1
}
```

Because of this complexity, most programming languages give up on trying to reason too much about the program and therefore pass the responsibility of not running silly busy loops back to the programmer.

Comment: Using the normal 32bit integer types, it definitely halts ;-)

Comment: It doesn't matter if it stops.  What matters is if the value of 'n' is ever used after the loop.  If not then the whole loop can be optimized away.

Comment: @JonStrayer: If it loops forever, then it better not get optimized away... that would be like "optimizing away" while (true) {}

Comment: @JonStrayer: You can't optimize away an infinite loop without changing the meaning of the program. What if I had a "fireTheMissiles()" call after the infinite loop?

Comment: @ChrisMiskowiec I agree it's exactly like that -- but if the `while(true) {...}` *provably* does nothing, then that's a perfectly fine optimization, as well. I think the "fireTheMissiles" scenario is a bit of a contrived scenario. Does anyone really use *processor time* to delay something catastrophic?

Comment: @NickC: The hard part is the "provably" bit. While some sorts of effectless while loops are straightfoward to optimize (and many compilers will do so), its easy to get in a slippery slope of properties that get harder and harder to prove and everyone gives up at some point.

Comment: Actually, in the newer C and C++ standards, infinite loops may execute in finite time. That covers the algorithm as shown in this question.

Comment: I didn't say you could optimize away while(true) in general.  But if the block has no side effects or used values you can.  An infinite loop that calculates no used values and has no side effects is a bug.

Comment: @JonStrayer: OK, its my turn tu be pedantic now :) What about `for(n=4; is_sum_of_two_primes(n); n+=2){}  printf("the goldbach conjecture is false!");`? The loop is fully effectless and side-effect free but you don't want to optimize it out and falsely break the news that you found a counterexample to a liong standing conjecture! And just in case you want to say that my point is moot because a sensible person would put the "n" in the printf then I'm not listening :P

Comment: @ missingno  And you are accusing me of being pedantic?  "-)  No doubt you can others can come up with examples were an infinite loop is preventing a bad thing from happening.  What you can't do is come up with a realistic scenario where we want to keep the loop.  In theory (and fact) you can't eliminate the loop without changing the meaning of the program.  In practice the loop is broken.

Comment: Here is a realistic scenario: I have a bug in my program, which sometimes creates an infinite loop. Fairly easy to detect once it's happening. Now if you optimize that away, I might not detect the problem (there are sideeffects, eg I withdraw the wrong amount from an account, but not as obvious as an infinite loop).

Comment: @yi_H You are also likely to have many other bugs in your program, with varying difficulty of detecting. Relying on infinite loops to expose your bugs is a bit unrealistic

Answer (score 18):

Get a better implementation. Many C++ compilers I know would remove much more complex code with no side effects than this.

Comment: Oh no! How will we speed up the program when our boss complains it's too slow? ;)

Comment: How does this answer the question???

Comment: @MatthewFlynn: It proves that the "problem" the OP sees is based on an incorrect fact, and therefore there is no problem at all.

Comment: @MatthewFlynn: interestingly, my answer was deleted by a mod, though saying a similar thing (granted, DeadMG was first though, but the rationale is odd :)).

Comment: @DeadMG The question said nothing about C++, the example code is not C++, and some people in some places *do* want this to execute.

Comment: @James Why would anyone want this to execute? As the question said, the only reason that makes sense is to have code that takes time, and there are better ways to do that.

Answer (score 3):

Commonly (and probably the only valid use for this) used in micro-controllers to control timing accurately, however most likely to be written in Assembler (or inline assembler in a C programmer) as the programmer then has absolute control over the instructions used, hence the time taken.

Answer (score 3):

This code may do nothing as you think it does, but what if, taking C# as example, I had overloaded the + operator.

```
public static int operator +(int one, int two) {/* implement crazy operation here */}
```

In the overload, I'd generate a frame and scale the operator to sync for 60fps.

This "useless" loop has now become a game that stops at the 100000000th frame. Not so useless heh?

Your inability to clearly define "useless code" is why the compiler can't deal with it.

Comment: Can the compiler see that the + operator is overloaded?  Then we still don't have a problem.

Comment: Even if the compiler didn't, the CLR can.

Answer (score 2):

There's 2 things to mention here. The first is that, many compilers as DeadMG said might optimize out code like this. As you probably know, if the point of the code was to take time, then this is inaccurate and dependent on the frequency of the processor.

The second thing to point out is your mentioning of "effect-less". It might not be what you mean, but many devs (especially those who are fans of functional programming, and its associated paradigms) advocate that you should avoid side-effects almost entirely - that is to say, have no external state. Generally speaking, programming in this way requires that you return some value from every function, thus it doesn't apply to the trivial example that you posted - but does to less-trivial examples.

Answer (score 2):

**To create an extreme loading condition**

One use of the Unix [yes](http://www.codeforge.com/read/126659/yes.c__html) application, which uses a similar loop construct, is to exercise the CPU to simulate high load.

It also provides a continuous "y" output for use with responses to older versions of Unix command lines.

I realise that the `yes` application is providing a measurable side-effect and so would not get optimised away, but the point I'm making is that fast, tight loops serve as useful load tests.

Answer (score 1):

As @BillMichell suggests in his comment, the point is to consume time, assumably to allow something else to happen.  Most modern languages have a better way to do this--telling the thread or process to `sleep` or `wait` for a specified period of time.  In the bad old days, that wasn't an option.

Answer (score 1):

2 reasons first is that to fully remove all dead code compilers would need to solve the [halting problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem) which is impossible and many compilers don't even try

second sometimes the programmer want a delay/busy loop there for various reasons (including simply slowing everything down so when Mr. Boss tells you to speed it up you can remove a 0 from the upper bound)

Comment: To be able to remove all dead code in all possible programs they would need to solve the halting problem.  That's not necessary in the above loop.

Answer (score 1):

First languages have most probably nothing to do with the issue. Definitions of languages give the observable behavior and they don't consider duration as observable behavior excepted for very special purpose functions.

Thus you are speaking about implementation choice.

As a documented case, let's look at gcc.

In early gcc documentation, they stated that they purposely didn't remove empty loops as they were most probably there for a timing purpose.

In newer one, they now state they have reversed their decision as empty loops are now most often due to other optimizations (which may remove all existing content) and they warn that empty loops will be removed if gcc is able to show that they will terminate.